# Domain Mapping in WPMU

Tags: mapping, dns, plesk

I'm running WordPress MultiUser and a plugin to allow for domain mapping.
I have a subdomain site  subdomain.domain.com
and I want domain2.com to point to it. 
My tech buddy double checked my WP settings and said everything was good there.

When I go to my existing subdomain.domain.com site I am now redirected to domain.com registration page.
When I go to domain2.com I get the following:

The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Prior to the domain mapping attempt the sub.domain.com site worked fine 
with sub.domain.com defined in Plesk as an alias of domain.com

I have domain2.com refined in Plesk as an alias of domain.com
I was told to have domain2.com made into an alias of sub.domain.com
but I don't see how to do that in Plesk.

Cloudflare is redirecting the domain2.com to the server correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to [contact CloudFlare](http://support.cloudflare.com/cgi/discussion/new) so we can actually look at the zone file & then check any redirect rules on your server.

Just a quick note that [mapped domains](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tt-cloudflare-wpmu-plugin/faq/) need to be added as individual domains, if not a subdomain of root domain,  so that's why it is important for us to look at the zone file. If you're simply adding subdomains to a domain already added, then that is a different issue (WPMU plugin is also available through outside developer that only works for subdomains).